# Jsoup matching with regex

Tags: java, jsoup

I came across a problem using jsoup. I can't match the `<div id="shout_132684">` those digits are changing. How should I match those?

```
Elements content = doc.select("div:matches(id=\"shout_.+?\")");
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the *startswith* CSS selector `^=`. It is supported by Jsoups `.select(...)`.

You can do it like this:

```
doc.select("div[id^=shout]");
```

This is an full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Document parse = Jsoup.parse("<div id=\"shout_23\"/>" +
                                 "<div id=\"shout_42\"/>" +
                                 "<div id=\"notValidId\"/>" +
                                 "<div id=\"shout_1337\"/>");

    Elements divs = parse.select("div[id^=shout");

    for (Element element : divs) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
<div id="shout_23"></div>
<div id="shout_42"></div>
<div id="shout_1337"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

For more accurate parsing you can still do it with regular expressions:

```
Elements content = doc.select("div[id~=(shout_)[0-9]+]");
```